# Repeating rows of a matrix based on a vector in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector, vectorization, lapply

I want to repeat the rows of a matrix (`M`) based on the values of a vector (`rep_vec`). In this case, the first row will be repeated once, the second twice, and the third three times.

```
M <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3,ncol = 3)

#> M
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    4    7
# [2,]    2    5    8
# [3,]    3    6    9

rep_vec <- matrix(1:3, nrow = 3,ncol = 1)

#> rep_vec
#     [,1]
#[1,]    1
#[2,]    2
#[3,]    3
```

I managed to do it using `lapply` an on a function (`rep_matrix`) just to avoid the for-loop structure. However, I am not quite pleased with my solution, and I think I should be missing something because to me seems like a trivial problem with no one-line solution.

```
rep_matrix <- function(i){
  return(rep(x= M[,i], times =rep_vec))
}

list_repmatrix <- lapply(seq_along(1:ncol(M)),
                         rep_matrix)

rep_matrix <- matrix(unlist(list_repmatrix), 
                     ncol = ncol(M) ,  
                     byrow=FALSE)

#> rep_matrix
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    7
#[2,]    2    5    8
#[3,]    2    5    8
#[4,]    3    6    9
#[5,]    3    6    9
#[6,]    3    6    9
```

Does anyone have a more elegant/faster solution for it or can recommend a better approach to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to repeat each column individually - you can repeat entire rows using a subset with repeated row indices:

```
## We use this as the row indices
## This will work whether `rep_vec` is a 1-column matrix
## Or if it is a vector (as implied by its name)
rep(seq_along(rep_vec), rep_vec)
[1] 1 2 2 3 3 3


M[rep(seq_along(rep_vec), rep_vec), ]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    4    7
# [2,]    2    5    8
# [3,]    2    5    8
# [4,]    3    6    9
# [5,]    3    6    9
# [6,]    3    6    9
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```r
M[rep(1:3, 1:3),]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    4    7
#> [2,]    2    5    8
#> [3,]    2    5    8
#> [4,]    3    6    9
#> [5,]    3    6    9
#> [6,]    3    6    9
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it work: Using tidyverse.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
as.matrix(uncount(as_tibble(M),rep_vec))
     V1 V2 V3
[1,]  1  4  7
[2,]  2  5  8
[3,]  2  5  8
[4,]  3  6  9
[5,]  3  6  9
[6,]  3  6  9
>
```